# How can I take the errorbars into account in regression analysis?

Tags: regression, error

I used regression analysis to fit the data shown below. The problem is that the R-square in the output is low (0.55). This is because Regression analysis does not take into account the Errors in each data point.

How can I do it so?[image: Up: Measurements with errorbars, Down: Excel regression output]

Comment: Questions that are only about how to use Excel are off topic here. If you have a statistical question, please edit to clarify, otherwise this will be closed.

Comment: Hi gung, I am new to stackexchange and I didn't know that. I am not sure then where can I find what I am looking for. For the rest, if necessary close the question.

Comment: For example, if you wanted to know how to take the errors in Y for each datum into account in a regression model, you could ask that here. 'How to do it in Excel' would be off topic (I'm also not sure it can be done in Excel in a straightforward way).

Comment: Since this is also a good question, I changed my post in order to find this out. Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by "Regression analysis does not take into account the Errors" ? What are the errors? Are they known (how)?

Comment: Hi Tim, the Errors are the errorbars that you can see in the first picture. These consist of systematic and random errors. I am not sure how to take the into account when doing a linear regression analysis (as for example one would draw a straight line (the best estimate) on a graph containing these points, while making sure that the line crosses all the points.

Comment: You won't improve $R^2$ much, but you can accommodate the error bars using [weighted least squares regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=weighted+least+squares+regression).

Comment: 1) This does not look like a linear model. 2) The y-axis errors look asymmetric, long tails in y+ direction. Where do the error bars come from and what justification is there for assuming symmetry? I would transform y-axis data using log or square root, replot, and fit with non-linear model.